# Boostrap 4 - best way to pack and center some content in 1 row/2 columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have some text and icon at first line, and i tried to pack it in 2 columns, aligned beside each other.

I suppose there is many ways to format text (unordered lists, for example). Also, I probably may use Font Awesome icons instead of img tag in my code.

Regardless of formatting text my problem is positioning texts and icons in center  of left/right column.

If I try to make text centered, icons stay at left corner of column, or icons and text are centered left in column etc. I tried to make media objects and align them but no results, too.

Shortly: all solutions I've tried results in text and belonging icons which are not aligned to center of columns.

I want it to look like this: https://prnt.sc/mb3s2i

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wLy5ce4o/

HTML:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row ">
<div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:#000; ">
<div class="media d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:50px;">
<div class="media-left media-top">
<img src="images/xyz.png" class="media-object" style="width:60px; color:#f636363;">
</div>
<div class="media-body">
<p>
<ul id="test1">
<li style="font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li style="font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li style="font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li style="font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li style="font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li style="font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li style="font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="media" style="padding-top:50px">
<div class="media-left media-top">
<img src="images/xyz1.png" class="media-object" style="width:60px; color:#f636363;">
</div>
<div class="media-body">
<p>
<ul id="test">
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="media" style="padding-top:50px;">
<div class="media-left media-middle">
<img src="images/xyz2.png" class="media-object" style="width:60px; color:#f636363;">
</div>
<div class="media-body">
<p>
<ul id="test">
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="media" style="padding-top:50px;">
<div class="media-left media-bottom">
<img src="images/xyz3.png" class="media-object" style=" padding-top:-10px; width:60px; color:#f636363;">
</div>
<div class="media-body">
<p>
<ul id="test" style=" padding-top:10px; width:60px; color:#f636363;">
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test1 {

 list-style:none;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#fff; 
 letter-spacing: 0;
 line-height: 0,5rem;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 80px;
 }




  #test {

 list-style:none;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#636363; 
 letter-spacing: 0;
 line-height: 1rem;
 }
```

Comment: try grid and use flex to lay the element in the middle for each grid

Comment: Hello, thanx for answer but  I'm not sure I understand what you exactly mean

Comment: i added your fiddle. take a look

Answer (score 1):

What happen here basically is i create two grid that take up the whole screen, and if you want equal column, put max-width in simple-one and simple-two. then you create flex inside grid that center itself. if you wan show from top just create another div with display: flex and flex-direction to column and self-align to top. check your fiddle i added inside https://jsfiddle.net/omnb12dw/2/ . If you are beginner, it time to start learning flex and grid.

```
<div class="simple-grid">
  <div class="simple-one">
    <p>
    Some Paragraph
    </p>
    <p>
    Add More and it will follow center
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="simple-two">
    <p>
    this is just the design
    </p>
    <p>
    it should be the same
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

    div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.simple-grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-areas: 'a a';
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.simple-one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;  
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.simple-two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

Comment: CSS grid rocks! Nice example

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try to do it as you suggested. By the way, im using Bootstrap 4 on this site, It will be no problem to combine section(s) with CSS grid and section(s) made in Bootstrap ?

Comment: there won't be any issues. just avoid giving the class name same as bootstrap classes. maybe minor styling issues with bootstrap base classes

Comment: Hello, i 've implemented your solution and it essentially works but there is new problem: Now it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/mb8azn Is there any fix to make it looks like this: https://prnt.sc/mb3s2i - icons on left, text on right side? Also, when i test draft site on mobile device, icon from left column and some text moves over border with a section above (icon dont stay inside of column). Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wj3kngu7 I really would appreciate any help!

Comment: edited your fiddle. Basically, you can nest grid and flex again. https://jsfiddle.net/6uag3ckv/2/

Comment: just mindful about your column, row gap for grid, padding and margin. when you nested inside, you will see more borders if you put border styling in your css,

Comment: Hi, thanks man!

First, i have to say that i finally made it good for me, but on fiddle it looks wrong.
( There was a problem when i tested it on mobile so i changed some things in your code and implemented this) 
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z2fLvmo7/
How it really looks on browser(s), mobile etc. : http://prntscr.com/mbrzqx

Columns side by side, icons, lists and icons in right column... - everything is okay and it looks perfect to me.

But, if you take a look to fiddle you will see that lists are uhmm under each other.

I really do not know why it looks strange on fiddle.

Comment: As i said it works verry well at this moment, but there is problem with width of left collum / border bettween left and right collumn - border is not centered in regards to previous section. Can u help me how to make widths of left and right collumns equal ?

How it looks now: http://prntscr.com/mbs6wm

Comment: remove grid-template-areas and put this style " grid-template-columns : 1fr 1fr;" . it will give you equal column

Comment: for mobile device, use media queries with proper screen ratio. same class, different styles

Comment: best is test with mozilla developer edition and chrome browser. you can inspect the design and realize the problems

Comment: hi, i changed grid-template-areas with grid-template-columns: 1fr 1 fr, now it looks good on large screens but on mobile it looks bad. Columns are one under each other, but "left columns" seems uhmmm cropped.... 

Can u tell me how to use media queries properly in this case? I need both collumns one under each other with max width on mobile phones... I wanted to build entire site in bootstrap and im confused for a bit

Comment: i added some queries to css and in general it works good, but there is little white line on right side of first/left columns, and content in left/top (on phone) and right/bottom (on phone) is not centered 
fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hsxjez0w/

Comment: if that the case you can't use vanilla css. try checkout bootstrap grid too. the principle is same. try to arrange div in the order that you want. simple way to draw out all the possible div nested inside and slowly translate into bootstrap class